# How do I test the output of a JSON data view in CakePHP?

Tags: json, debugging, cakephp, dataview, requesthandler

So I am trying to create an Android mobile application and I am using CakePHP as my serverside. I will not be needing any HTML views, I will only be responding with JSON objects.

I have taken a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent and with that I've created this:

```
class LocationsController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    function index()
    {
        $locations = $this->Location->getNearest();
        $this->set(compact('locations'));
        $this->set('_serialize', array('locations'));
    }
}
```

and I have added this to my `routes.php`:

```
Router::mapResources('locations');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Nothing is displayed when I run this apart from the default CakePHP layout style. If I remove the index.ctp view file, I get an error that it can't find the view file. Why does it still require a view file? I thought with the serialize approach it does not need a view. I have tried looking in the Google Chrome developer console and there is no response that contains the JSON object. However, the MySQL has performed perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `$this->render(false);` between

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

and

```
function index()
```

Now it doesn't require an index.ctp file anymore.

See [this link](http://www.sethcardoza.com/2009/07/disabling-layouts-and-views-in-cakephp/) for more information.

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION). Either way, this will just obliterate all output in the browser. I won't be able to test or see my JSON data if I use render(false).

Comment: Oh, darn. Yeah, you are right. I suspected that would've done the job, but this is with JSON data. Then I'm not able to help you, sorry.

Comment: Thanks nevertheless =). I used public $viewClass = 'Json'; and it seems to have done the trick on the browser end. I haven't tested it on the Android end though. I'm just worried about how Android will receive the data. I don't want it to receive any html, css or javascript content.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same thing, using the REST API, as I want the response in the JSON.
What I did is I used the Chrome advanced rest client. In that I made a request to my localhost server by using the appropriate GET method, and it succeeded.

like: `GET /users/view/103.json`

you will get the response as:

```
{"users":{"User":{"id":"103","username":"abc","password":"xyz",
 "email-id":"abc@xyz.com"}}}
```